# Transaction with FTP adapter

Tags: biztalk

I want to pull something from the server (no delete), parse the file in the pipeline component, process the file, if everything goes successfully, I want the adapter delete the file.

i am thinking to enlist the parsing into the pipeline context, this way, I am picturing if the file cannot be parsed, the file will not get to the message box, therefore it will be deemed as a failed transaction, question, will the adapter participate in this transaction? in other words, my goal is to instruct the adapter to delete the file from the server **ONLY** when the pipeline processed successfully (transaction is commited), the file is left untouched on the server if the pipeline failed (transaction is rolled back, no message is commited to msg box)

Is this achievable? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with Biztalk but I have done FTP in a transaction framework.  Delete-on-commit is not a strictly safe strategy.  For a two-phase commit, you would need a temp directory on the server.  In commit phase 1, move the file to the temp directory.  In commit phase 2, delete the file from temp.  For rollback, move the file back from temp to the original folder.  Even that is not safe from sudden power-off (i.e. automatically rolled back), but that's probably as good as it gets.

Comment: agree, I'll probably do it this way, thanks for input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a little experiment is in order.  BizTalk, as part of it's nature, will not delete anything until it has been peristed to the message box.  That being said, persitence might happen before PipeLine execution.  So, the receive adapter receives the file, perists it to the message box and deletes the file.  The message might subsequently fail in the pipeline.  If this is the case, then the message is a bad format and it will have to be subsequently resubmitted by the sender.  If you want to keep this message, you'll have to pick it up with Failed Message Routing.  You can then write it to a directory and implement a resubmit pattern. Or, you can pick up the file via Failed Message Routing and put it back on the FTP server (this is sort of a compensation step).

On the otherhand, if the pipeline fails and the message isn't deleted fromt he server... you're fine.

Comment: Hi, Chris, I actually did some tests here, unfortunately the adapter behaves in the first scenario you talked about. I also see if there is any possibility to use the before get, after get command with some macros, but no luck as well. So now I abandon this thought and call a helper component to delete the file in the pipelien component

Comment: If the file fails in the pipeline, what is the resolution?  Does the sender have to resend the file with the correction made?  You could use Failed message routing to pickup the file and route it to some sort of notificaiton for the sender.  Just curious on the details.